# how to fix CSS parse error: Semicolon or block is expected?

Tags: css, sass, minify

Hi I want to know how to fix following CSS code error. When I tried to minify it I got this error.

```
`
  522 |.the-icons.span3 .i-name {
  523 | padding-left: 40px;
  524 |}
  525 |@media only screen and min-width: 768px and max-width: 959px {
---------------------------------------^
  526 | .the-icons.span3 {
  527 |     width: 33.333%;
  528 | }`
```

Comment: Syntax should be like this : `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px)`

Comment: [Each media feature expression must be surrounded by parentheses.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add like this.

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:959px){
  .the-icons.span3 {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}
```